# how to get data from asp.net api restful webservice from node.js server?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, node.js, rest

I try to get data from my asp.net restful webservice from my node.js server but I dont know how to do it. I have tried some ways (using jquery, but get some error, and I dont know why). 
The url to get data from asp.net restful is something like this: "http://localhost:20034/api/Homepage/friendlist?id=1"

Hope someone can help me. Thanks!

Comment: There's isn't enough information in there to start answering your question. What error do you get, can you provide sample code showing you jquery call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about that error you are getting when using jQuery. You would need to provide more details about that.

In general though, if you want to make an HTTP request using node.js, you can use the http.get() function.

For example (from the official node.js documentation):

```
var http = require('http');
http.get("http://www.google.com/index.html", function(res) {
  console.log("Got response: " + res.statusCode);
}).on('error', function(e) {
  console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
});
```

If you wanted to use that in a separate function you would call it and provide a callback. This is important due to the asynchronous nature of the http.get() call. Here is an example:

```
var http = require('http');

var callService = function(url, callback) {
    http.get(url, function(res) {
        return callback(null, res);
    }).on('error', function(err) {
        return callback(err);
    });
}

callService("http://www.google.com/index.html", function(err, res){
    if (err) console.log("Got error: " + err.message);
    else console.log("Final result:" + res);
});
```

Comment: Thanks JWK, I wrote an example as the following to test your answer: 

    function evaluate(expression){
     http.get("http://www.google.com/index.html", function (res) {
      console.log("Got response: " + res);
        }).on('error', function (e) {
                return e.message;
            });
        console.log('Final result');
    }

and then I realize that the statement "console.log('Final result');" is executed before the statement: "console.log("Got response: " + res);" do. This means that I can't get the result from http.get before my "evaluate" function returns.

Comment: This's the error I got when try to call require('jquery'):
http://www.flickr.com/photos/90067471@N08/8181018304/sizes/l/in/photostream/

You can follow the link to see the error picture. Sorry for this inconvenience, because I'm new to stackoverflow! :)

Comment: No, that's not how asynchronous calls in node.js work. You will need to work will callbacks. I added an example on how to wrap the http.get() into a function and call it to my answer. As for the jQuery error, it looks like you are on Windows and the node-jquery module doesn't seem to work on windows currently (see https://github.com/coolaj86/node-jquery)